# Using DXF file in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, autocad, cad

I have a DXF file provided by a customer, it is made up of polylines, polygons and arrows with annotations pointing to the features.

I want to extract certain features but also associate the annotations with them

When I load the DXF into ArcGIS Pro I get various groups:

- Annotation
- Multipatch
- Polyline
- Polygon
- Point

Within each of these groups there are multiple layers

So it seems to be quite a mess to try and sort. Is there a good way to go about sorting a CAD file in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: What is your end goal - to convert this into a geodatabase?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to include that